# Unmerged Cell For Loop skipping cells

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl and found some code through goolging about unmerging cells in an xlsx workbook.

I got the code to work, but found that it was not removing all the merged cells in a single pass through. I set it up to run using a while loop and solved the issue, but was wondering what I am doing wrong to cause the skipping in the first place. Any insight would be helpful.

Code:

```
 import openpyxl 
 wb = './filename.xlsx'

 ws = wb[sheetname] 

def remove_merged(sheet_object):
     merged = ws.merged_cell_ranges
     while len(merged)>0:
         for mergedRNG in merged:
             ws.unmerge_cells(range_string = mergedRNG)
         merged = ws.merged_cell_ranges
     return len(merged)

remove_merged(ws)
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: When I run the for loop without the while condition, there are merged cells left. Why isn't the for loop removing all the merged cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ws.merged_cell_ranges` is mutable so you need to be careful that it is not directly used in any for-loop, because the implicit counter won't take into account that the property has been recalculated. This is a common gotcha in Python illustrated by:

```
l = list(range(10))
for i in l:
    print(i)
    l.pop(0) # anything that affects the structure of the list
```

The following is how to avoid this:

```
for rng in ws.merged_cell_ranges[:]: # create a copy of the list
   ws.unmerge(rng) # remove range from original
```

PS. just copying stuff from an internet search isn't really advisable. There are several sites with outdated or unnecessarily complex code. Best referring to the documentation or asking on the mailing list.